# VMware Player: "No protocol specified" error after upgrading to ubuntu 14.04

Tags: upgrade, gtk, vmware-player

I had installed "VMware-Player-6.0.1-1379776.x86_64.bundle" in my Ubuntu 13.10.
Today i Upgrade to Ubuntu 14.4 LTS. Now when I try to launch VMware player it shows a messagebox:

```
Before you can run vmware several modules mush be compiled, and loaded into the running kernel
```

I pressed "install" button. But gets error, it doesn't start.

So I tried to reinstall it by typing:

```
./VMware-Player-6.0.1-1379776.x86_64.bundle
```

Now it shows,

```
Extracting VMware Installer...done.
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar": liboverlay-scrollbar.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module": libunity-gtk-module.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
No protocol specified
No protocol specified


[######################################################################] 100%
The system is up to date.  Nothing has been modified.
```

---

How can I launch VMware Player, what i need to install now? My win8 is working with VMware Player. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Download the new [vmware-player 6.02](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/free#desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_player/6_0), works fine with ubuntu 14.04.